# Faster way of adding sumifs formulas into large range

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I am wondering if there is a faster way of adding (and calculating) a number of formulas into a larger range.

So the range counts 22 columns with 14235 rows each. Every column has its own formula most of them are sumifs with 5 criterias.

My approach is actually very simple, but probably not the fastest. 
It's just selecting the range of each column and insert the formula.

```
Sheet1.Range("G4:G14238").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(sumRangeA,criteria_range1,RC[-6],criteria_range2,RC[-5],criteria_range3,RC[-4],criteria_range4,RC[-3],criteria_range5,RC[-2])"
Sheet1.Range("H4:H14238").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(sumRangeB,criteria_range1,RC[-7],criteria_range2,RC[-6],criteria_range3,RC[-5],criteria_range4,RC[-4],criteria_range5,RC[-3])"
...and so on
```

This actually takes a while, I believe because excel is inserting and calculating everything after having inserted.

So I tried deactivating the auto calculation before inserting the formulas and let excel calculate everything once every formulas were filled, but that even took longer (nearly twice as long). Not sure if I used the code correctly, though

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual

Sheet1.Range("G4:G14238").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(sumRangeA,criteria_range1,RC[-6],criteria_range2,RC[-5],criteria_range3,RC[-4],criteria_range4,RC[-3],criteria_range5,RC[-2])"
Sheet1.Range("H4:H14238").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(sumRangeB,criteria_range1,RC[-7],criteria_range2,RC[-6],criteria_range3,RC[-5],criteria_range4,RC[-4],criteria_range5,RC[-3])"

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

To give you a better understanding what I try to achieve:
Until now I have these formulas in a regular excel table (no vba at all). It is working, but very slow. If I filter for one condition it takes up to two minutes to show me the results. 
Since I use this table daily it's very time consuming and rather inefficient.

So I thought creating something with vba might help to make it faster. 
My idea was to insert the formulas, let it calculate and then paste everything as values. That should allow me to work faster with the file. But as my approach takes very much time too, it's not the perfect solution until now.

Are you guys able to help me with that? I am happy with any other approach that might help fasten up the work flow!

Thanks in advance!

Best,

Ramon

Comment: You could use your second piece of code to add the formulas in then use `Sheet1.Calculate` to ensure the formulas are calculated. Then you could replace the formulas with their values e.g. `Sheet1.Range("A4:Z14238").Value = Sheet1.Range("A4:Z14238").Value` this will means there are no formulas to be calculated each time you filter your results

Comment: What @Jordan offered is correct. But it can be done in excel itself instead of vba (PasteSpecial).

Comment: @Jordan will try that out and see if it faster, thanks!
at Masoud The problem is that I need the formulas everyday. The table calculates everyday updates values.

Comment: Your solution may be to turn off Automatic Recalculation for this worksheet, and manually recalculate only when you need to.

Comment: @RichHolton that's actually so simple but true...I got a solution now where I deactivate calculation when starting the workbook and calculate cells and ranges with a macro. Thanks for the hind!

Answer (score 0):

A nice simple loop would do it:

```
Sub SumIf()
Dim ASCII As Long
Dim iRef As Long
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

iRef = 6
For ASCII = 71 To 93
    Sheet1.Range(Chr(ASCII) & "4:" & Chr(ASCII) & "14238").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(sumRange,criteria_range1,RC[-" & iRef & "],criteria_range2,RC[-" & (iRef - 1) & "],criteria_range3,RC[-" & (iRef - 2) & "],criteria_range4,RC[-" & (iRef - 3) & "],criteria_range5,RC[-" & (iRef - 4) & "])"
    iRef = iRef  + 1
Loop

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach, unfortunately this won't work because the SumRange differs for each column.